# Home button disappearing on php page

Tags: php, jquery-mobile, html

The "Events" page is using php to output info from an xml file. I placed the page and header divs at the top of the file before the php starts.

While the "Back" button appears on that page the "Home" icon button does not. Both of these buttons appear on static pages (i.e. "Maps & Directons").

How can I restore the home button?

[Website here](http://www.stanford.edu/group/webdev/cgi-bin/m/).

Comment: Can we see your code for the header?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

in your header on the news page: http://www.stanford.edu/group/webdev/cgi-bin/m/news/

(View source)

You are missing the home link

```
<div data-role="header"> 
    <h1>News</h1> 
</div><!-- /header -->
```

Change to this on the news page and you should be set:

```
<div data-role="header"> 
    <h1>News</h1> 
    <a href="index.html" data-icon="home" data-iconpos="notext" data-direction="reverse" class="ui-btn-right">Home</a> 
</div><!-- end header -->
```

Answer (score 0):

Your header should stay the same throughout each page, whether you hardcode it on each `data-role="page"`, or make it static:

```
<div data-role="header">
    <a href="index.html" data-icon="back">Back</a>
    <a href="index.html" data-icon="home"></a>
</div>
```

Can we see your code though?